# Tricky exponentialccomposite function

Tags: exponential-function

I have a composite function problem.
Given $f(x) =e^{-x}$
Find $f^{215} (x)$
I use graphing calculator and I realise $f^4(x$) is the same as $f^2(x)$. With this is mind I'd say $f^{215}$ is the same as $f^3$.

But how could I show it.

Comment: I've added one (of several, not particularly standard) way to indicate that superscripted numbers on function names represent repeated composition (not repeated differentiation).  Does this capture your intent?

Comment: @EricTowers Sorry but I think that your interpretation is really uncorrect. You should rollback and maybe ask to the OP about your ideed before to edit the question in such way.

Comment: @gimusi : The first signal that composition was intended was "composite" in the title and in the body of the question.  The second signal was "But this is a composite function problem. Can we use differentiation to solve it." as the first comment to your answer.  OP seems very clear that composition, not differentiation, is intended.

Comment: @gimusi : The third signal is OP's use of "f{f(x)}, f{f(f(f(x))} and so on" in further comments.

Comment: @EricTowers In teh original question the OP said "I use graphing calculator and I realise f4(x) is the same as f2(x)". Is that true for composition?

Comment: @gimusi : Of course not.  Does this mean the OP used the composition he said he was using with his calculator?

Comment: @EricTowers I think the OP can clarify that in a moment.

Comment: @Eric Towers. I got this problem from a friend of mine. And my first thought in this question was applying the differentiation approach. But my friend used the composite function approach and he could not solve the problem. The aim of asking this question is to see whether this question should be solved with differentiation approach or composite function approach.

Comment: @arthuranderson : There is *nothing* in your question indicating that there are two methods under discussion or that differentiation is even a candidate.  How did you expect others to guess that from what you wrote?

Comment: @Eric Towers. My intent is to use composite function  approach but it seems this question require differentiation approach to make sense.

Comment: Since there does not seem to be any coherent way to convert what is actually written in your Question to what you meant, I have rolled back my edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that

- $f'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}e^{g(x)}=e^{g(x)}\cdot g'(x)=-f(x)$
- $f''(x)=f(x)$
- $f'''(x)=f'(x)=-f(x)$
- $\dots$

therefore your guess is correct.

To prove it rigorously, from $f'(x)=-f(x)$, we have that for any $n\in N$

$$f^{2n-1}(x)=-f(x)\implies f^{2n}(x)=-\frac{d}{dx}f^{2n-1}(x)=-\frac{d}{dx}f(x) =-f'(x)=f(x)$$

$$\implies f^{2n+1}(x)=\frac{d}{dx}f^{2n}(x)=\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=-f(x)$$

and we are looking for $n$ from $1$ to $107$.

Comment: But this is a composite function problem. Can we use differentiation to solve it.

Comment: I was thinking about using the relation f{f(x)} to see the pattern. But I could not simplify for higher f.

Comment: @arthuranderson By chain rule we have $f'(x)= d(-x)/dx\cdot f(x)=-f(x)$ and so on.

Comment: Can you show me also the induction method?

Comment: Does this mean this question we cannot use the relation f{f(x)}, f{f(f(f(x))} and so on for higher f.

Comment: @arthuranderson I think we don't need induction! I add something more on that.

Comment: Okay @gimusi. Thank you. But my one last question. Is that for this question we cannot we use the relation f(f(x)), and so on for higher x to solve?

Comment: @arthuranderson Why should we use $f(f(x))$?

Comment: Ok @gimusi I got it. Thank you.

Comment: @arthuranderson You are welcome! Bye